# Mouseover effect to change a center div when mousing over other divs

Tags: javascript, css, html, mouseover

I'd like to make a page with a div with an image in the direct center, and when the user mouseover other divs (the whole thing, not just links) I'd like to have the image change.

Is it required to use javascript for this? What's the simiplest solution (onmouseover?). I don't know javascript very well. Is there a good tutorial on this, I googled but had trouble finding anything about div swapping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery functions for this...Refer here
  [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

Answer (score 0):

I have Included some sample source code here....

here u have to replace image name and locations () as relative to Ur local system.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Detecting browser close in IE</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg()
{
document.getElementById("image").src="new image location here";
}

</script>
</head>
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div align="center">
<img src="imagelocation here" alt="myclass" id="image" />
</div>
<div id="div2" align="left" onmouseover="changeImg()">
Drag Ur mouse to  change image
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope This will help U.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. One thing I'm confused about is to do multiple divs, am I going to have to do several different functions? or is there a way to make one function to change one image with 5+ different divs? Is there a way to pass the image URL through the parenthesis part?

Comment: <div id="div2" align="left" onmouseover="changeImg('images/mytest.jpg')"  />